How to telegraph possible consequences to a large playerbase in a "Living World" environment?
It might be ages old, but there are still Play-By-Chat games using telnet as the main means of communication and to roll dice. Usually, these places have several "storytellers" or GMs, that tell a larger campaign in work together. Players are generally organized in spheres of characters that belong to one faction or group within the broader game, such as "street level Gothamites" or "Camarilla Vampires". And as a big note: Players are usually worldwide and in different timezones, so scheduling is often not happening more than posting an event and seeing who shows up, though some players bookmark that they want to go there.
Now, the main problem when it comes to playing like that is, that plots happen over several scenes, players change between scenes and often it is hard to read the room as in, what players understand or what the GM tries to accomplish: the only way of communication in a scene are pure text, with normal pose text, direct page messages, and OOC text. Outside of scenes, there are (semi) public bulletin boards (specific boards can be locked to players in a sphere) and a ticket system accessible by staff and the relevant players on each ticket. But again, all text.
Now, let's craft a situation as an example of why telegraphing is absolutely necessary:

ST: "Bob, you see a guy with a funky tool follow some sort of reading as he stumbles from the event site that blew up last week towards your group's holy place."

Now, Bob isn't one of the players (Alice and Charly) that, since last week, have been out to monitor the explosion site and informed the ST of that by opening a ticket. The bulletin board only contains a note that the place blew up and what is known to have happened there. Bob also might not be in the know that the guys with funky tools are possible dangers to the holy place (as their MO is desecrating such places), and Bob might not be aware of who to report to at the moment due to online times. Indeed, the whole sphere might not have players online at that moment that could assist Bob with either the information needed, or enough fighting power to get things done.
However, the ST also can't give Bob the info that Alice and Charly are digging up via their inter-scene job, as that would steal away their chance to act on things or have a scene to give information to others. That is not a bug, it's a feature: unless they tell somebody what they found, nobody should know, it is an incentive to go and research things!
But on the other hand, Bob is painfully aware that something is going on, and that he lacks information. This leads often to two outcomes: Some people do nothing, fearing they might blockade someone else's actions or plotlines or that the ST is out to get them and over precaution. Others act in rather aggressive and reckless manners based on the very incomplete information without even attempting to get more information and then justify it by saying "But my guy only knew X", caused by bad to no telegraphing that there could be consequences to actions or roughly what they might be.
So... what guidelines make a good telegraphed tell in a living world environment that on the one hand manages to give Bob enough guidance on what the consequences could be without disincentivizing people from doing their research/recon work in between run scenes?

Could you clarify what the goal is in telegraphing this? Is Bob's character supposed to be aware of these details, or is the idea to prevent Alice and Charly's plotline being derailed, or is it the ST's general policy in this game to make players aware when their actions will have major consequences?

@aantia People from being rash assholes derailing plotlines or being trapped in inaction for want of more information.

I'm just amazed to see a MUD/MUSH-relevant query on the site. :)

Ah the chaos of BBS games. Questions: how do you currently announce storylines/consequences/etc for public consumption? Are the private boards the reason there's disparity?

@CatLord mosty? word of mouth, call out on the public channels for ad-hoc stuff and pinning an event for planned stuff - but that's more "RP is going on" and people exchange information to one another in scenes... the BBs is surprisingly underused... and as explained: it's considered a feature, not a bug, that people need to share the information somehow.

Rather than telegraphing a scene's consequences to individual participants, telegraph the global limits on consequences to everybody.
If you've ever read through a Powered by the Apocalypse game you're probably familiar with countdowns. If not, I detail some elements of them in this answer, but here's an important introduction:

A countdown clock is a reminder to you as MC that your threats have impulse, direction, plans, intentions, the will to sustain action and to respond coherently to others'.
-- "Threats: Countdown Clocks", Apocalypse World 2e p. 117

Other drifts have used non-clock imagery to convey them - the essential elements of a countdown are

an escalating series of events
with consequences visible to the PCs
reflecting the motions of the threat if unopposed or aided by anyone

Some drifts use a countdown to frame the progression of a single shared story, such that only one exists at a time in the game, but from an Apocalypse World perspective you can have as many countdowns as you have active threats.
Translating to a Collaboratively GMed Text Game
When introducing a new threat, GMs collaborate to create a countdown for it. This doesn't encompass everything the threat will ever do, just its most immediate impulses. It's also not a binding series of events - just what the threat will do if the PCs do nothing, which they almost certainly won't.
As part of this countdown, GMs decide on events publicly visible to the PCs and what they say about a threat's current ambition. Regardless of who interacts with the threat or what they find out, this broad information about a threat's current ambition becomes visible to all PCs in the same way that publicly-knowable background information on the setting is visible.
A threat plays within its current ambition. Countdowns aren't absolute; they can be stopped or skipped ahead if other actors in the game halt a threat's ambition or give it a boost. But when a threat's acting under its own power it doesn't jump ahead.
When all of these things happen, PCs know the current ambitions of every threat in the game the same way they know common setting background information. So when interacting with an agent of a threat, they know the worst possible consequences of their actions. Even if they don't know which threat they're acting against, they still know the worst consequences possible.
And that might seem like you're providing a bunch of unearned information, but really it's just keeping you honest about your storytelling. Like if this is a fantasy game and you're just introducing an orc horde that would eventually topple the kingdom if nobody did anything, but it hasn't even set up camp yet, there are limits on the ramifications of what could happen when one player was interacting with one advance scout, right? They're not going to stop the entire horde in their tracks no matter what they do to this one scout, and similarly, even if they flub the interaction entirely that doesn't mean that everyone has to watch helplessly as the kingdom collapses.
